# String arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have an array of strings which when I iterate through and print its elements gives me unexpected results.

```
char currencies[][3] = {"EUR", "GBP", "USD", "JPY", "CNY"};

void show_currencies()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s - ", currencies[i]);
    }
}
```

when I call `show_currencies()` I get this on output.

```
EURGBPUSDJPYCNY - GBPUSDJPYCNY - USDJPYCNY - JPYCNY - CNY -
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour.

Thank you

Comment: any decent compiler should give error or at least warning for this

Comment: @chapper, @martani: I don't have a copy of the c standard near to hand, but I think that silently dropping the NUL byte in this case is explicitly allowed by the standard.  At least at one time, there would have been a reasonable amount of code that used this technique to initialize fix-size char arrays, because it's much more concise than simply listing the char values one by one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing the nul terminators the strings are actually 4 characters long. Each string is then over writing the previous string's null terminator*. Try instead:

```
char currencies[][4] = {"EUR", "GBP", "USD", "JPY", "CNY"};
```

*As pointed out by caf it is not "over writing the previous string's null terminator" as the null terminator is never copied into the array. It is a fluke that the string is does not have garbled output after the final '-'.

Comment: Yep - that'll be it... 

You have to allow space in your array for the null terminator as well as the actual content...

Comment: ephemient, that doesn't work (it's a compile-time error).  You must declare the size of all but the left-most dimension (the compiler has to know how long a row is to handle indexing).

Comment: This is right, except that each string isn't "overwriting the previous string's null terminator" - the nul terminators are never written at all, because the arrays being initialised only have 3 chars each.  (It was a complete fluke that the last array happened to be followed by a terminator at all).

Answer (score 8):

You're declaring it wrong.  This will work.  It just lets the compiler set up an array of pointers-to-const-chars:

```
const char *currencies[] = {"EUR", "GBP", "USD", "JPY", "CNY"};
```

EDIT: Making it a two-dimension array, like Charles Beattie's answer, works too, provided you allocate space for the null.  Also, specify that chars are `const`, per Christoph.

Comment: actually, both work (if you leave space for the terminating zero in the original code), but your version might be better as compilers will have an easier time to optimize this; in both cases, you should add `const` qualifiers, though

Comment: both the declarations are different. In OP's case, he is declaring a double char array, where as your declaration is a array of const char pointers. So, in your case he cannot modify the contents of the array, i mean he cannot do things like currencies[0][1] = 'x';

Comment: That's right, chappar.  It does not look like he's intending to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
char currencies[][3]
```

to

```
char currencies[][4]
```

strings in C are NULL terminated, to make their handling (in printing, copying etc) easier.
example: `char str[] = "ABC";`
will declare a string of 4 char with `\0` as the last char (index 3).

As a tip whenever on printing a char array you get unexpected results you might wanna check to see if the char array is NULL terminated or not.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an array of strings but an array of array-of-char. You could use:

```
char* currencies[] = {"EUR", "GBP", "USD", "JPY", "CNY"};  // untested
```

to allow for strings of different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  "EUR" is four characters long - three for the letters, one for the terminating null character.  Since you're explicitly specifying three-character arrays, the compiler is truncating, and so your data is strung together.  You're lucky there is apparently a zero character at the end of the array, or you could get all sorts of garbage.  Change your declaration to `char currencies[][4]`.

Answer (score 0):

My C is quite rusty, but try:

```
char currencies[][3] = {"EUR\0", "GBP\0", "USD\0", "JPY\0", "CNY\0"};
```

I'm just curious to know what happens

Comment: The compiler should issue a warning.

Comment: The same will hapen as your strings are 5 characters long.
 `"EUR\0" is equiv {'E','U','R','\0','\0'}`